# Can a ranger pick two humanoid races as their favored enemy at level 1, and then two more humanoid races at level 6?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger, dnd-beyond

Can a ranger pick two humanoid races as their favored enemy at level 1, and then two more humanoid races at level 6 or level 14?

My reading of the Favored Enemy feature is that any time the ranger chooses a favored enemy, be it at Level 1, 6 or 14, the ranger may alternately choose two humanoid races instead of one non-humanoid creature type. However, D&D Beyond does not allow a player to choose two more humanoid races at level 6 or 14 if they have previously chosen two humanoid races at level 1 or 6.

Is my interpretation of the Favored Enemy feature incorrect, or is D&D Beyond's implementation incorrect?

**Note:** My question is similar, but not a duplicate, to [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/68417/48191) one. That question is about a scenario where a ranger chooses a non-humanoid creature type as their favored enemy at level 1, and then wants to choose two humanoid races at level 6. My question is about a ranger who chooses two humanoid races at level 1, and wants to choose two more humanoid races at level 6.

Comment: This is a duplicate. Both questions are asking if you can choose two humanoids at 6th level.

Answer (score 3):

## Probably yes.

> **Favored Enemy**
> Choose a type of favored enemy: [...]. Alternatively, you can select two races of humanoid (such as gnolls and orcs) as favored enemies.

So when you get a Favored Enemy, you pick a type of enemy (dragon, undead, etc), or 2 humanoid races.

> You choose one additional favored enemy, as well as an associated language, at 6th and 14th level.

At 6th level, you pick another Favored Enemy. Not specifically a type, but a Favored Enemy. To me, that reads you either pick a type or 2 humanoid races, both at 6th level and at 14th.

That being said, the feature is a bit ambiguous, so I'd talk with your DM and agree on a specific ruling that will work well at your table.

Comment: Just so its clear, PHB specifically states "one" additional favored enemy.

Comment: @VittorioCarano Yes. That, to me, reads as "take one more instance of the Favored Enemy feature", which can be two humanoid races. I do get your point, but the fact that it doesn't say "one additional type of favored enemy" leans me towards my interpretation

Comment: As a dm, id allow it, but i hold with my assessment, RAW specifically states One

Answer (score -1):

No.
Phb 91 "Choose a favored type of enemy... Alternatively, you can select two races of humanoid...."

"You choose one additional favored enemy, as well as an associated language,  at 6th and 14th level"

You could select ONE humanoid race at levels 6 and 14, as well as an associated language.

Playing RAW, the addition of additional favored enemies at higher levels does not implicitly state that you may opt for the split humanoid option offered at level .